# Insert record using php and access database - getting "Wrong parameter count for odbc_exec()"

Tags: php, ms-access, sql-insert

Insert record using php and access database - getting "Wrong parameter count for odbc_exec()"  Everything works except I can't get it to insert into the database.

```
$R1=rand(1,20);
$db=odbc_connect('Eightball','','');
 $sql  = "SELECT * FROM theAnswers";
 $sql .= " WHERE id = " . $R1;
 $rs=odbc_exec($db,$sql);
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{       
 $FinalAnswer=odbc_result($rs,"Answer");
 $newdate = date('M j, Y');
 $newQuestion = $_POST["Question"];
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
 $Thereferrer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 }
$theIPAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

 echo $theIPAddress;
 echo $Thereferrer;
 echo $newQuestion;
 echo $FinalAnswer;
 echo $newdate;
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO theQuestions (ipaddress, referrer, Question, Answer, theDate)     VALUES ('$theIPAddress', '$Thereferrer', '$newQuestion', '$FinalAnswer', newdate)";
$rs=odbc_exec($db,$sql);
$result = odbc_exec($sql);
if (!$result) {exit('Execution failed!');}
```

Comment: Don't you need the $ on the newdate variable in the INSERT statement?

Comment: I am sure it is a problem with the date field for the insert statement. In access it is setup as date/time data type

Comment: tried $newdate, '$newdate'

Comment: See: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/datetime_sql.htm  this is for Delphi, but sames goes for PHP

Comment: I remove ipaddress, referrer, and their values and the query ran, but didn't update because data type is set "allow zero length no"

Answer (score 0):

The second-last line

```
$result = odbc_exec($sql);
```

is the one that's giving the "Wrong parameter count" error. That second call is also extraneous.

I was also concerned about the date format, but I tried it on my Windows server the following worked for me

```
<?php
$db = odbc_connect('db1', '', '');
$dateValue = date('M j, Y');
$sql = 
        "INSERT INTO phpTest (TextCol, DateCol) " .
        "VALUES ('testing', '" . $dateValue . "')";
echo $sql . "\r\n";
odbc_exec($db, $sql);
echo "Done.\r\n";
```

The test run was successful...

```
C:\__tmp>\php\php odbcTest.php
INSERT INTO phpTest (TextCol, DateCol) VALUES ('testing', 'Apr 10, 2013')
Done.
```

...and the row was indeed inserted into the table

[image: phpTest]

Still, `date('Y-m-d')` would be a safer choice.